# Anchor button to bottom of screen above tabbar ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

we have a couple screens where there is one button with one action to take, but the rest of the screen scrolls (full of info). So I want anchor the button to the bottom of the screen. This app has a tabbar, so the button is actually anchored 49pts above the base of the screen. This works just fine until someone goes to type into a text box. At this point the button that appears anchored at the bottom of the screen is just hanging out 49pts above the keyboard.

How do I fix this?

Here are a couple screen shots of what I'm talking about.
[image: Proper working of button]

[image: Text error]

Comment: would you like it to be behind the keyboard (just above the hidden tab bar) or just above the keyboard ?

Comment: Just above the keyboard, so that when they get done typing they can just hit the button to continue.

Comment: I believe you have somewhere in your code where you move that button, something like keyboardWillShow or textFieldDidBeginEditing. It would be useful to show this part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the code I was using incase anyone has a similar problem. Since the keyboard takes up half the screen I only moved the button and label half the distance of the toolbar.

```
- (void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif {
    _lblContinueBG.center = CGPointMake(_lblContinueBG.center.x, _lblContinueBG.center.y + 25);
    _btnContinue.center = CGPointMake(_btnContinue.center.x, _btnContinue.center.y + 25);
}
- (void) keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *)notif {
    _lblContinueBG.center = CGPointMake(_lblContinueBG.center.x, _lblContinueBG.center.y - 25);
    _btnContinue.center = CGPointMake(_btnContinue.center.x, _btnContinue.center.y - 25);
}
```

This page helped out a bunch too - similar post. [Creating object programmatically and changing that object's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554459/creating-object-programmatically-and-changing-that-objects-position)